# In a poker game with a double-sized deck, does a "Flush Pair" have a special rank?

Tags: poker-theory

Suppose I play a game of 5-card-draw with a relatively large table (>5 players), necessitating that I double the deck with two standard decks. In addition to adding 5-of-a-kind to the hand rankings (which I believe is ranked above a Royal Flush; please correct me if I'm mistaken) this also adds a few exotic hands to the possible draw. Such as:

- A two-pair flush (♥4, ♥4, ♥2, ♥2, ♥7)
- A one-pair flush (♥9, ♥9, ♥J, ♥8, ♥4)

Do either of these hands hold any kind of special rank in such a game, or are they just ranked the same as a regular Flush? Even if they're ranked the same, do I take the highest card of each hand (the ♥7 and ♥J respectively) or the highest pair of each hand (the ♥4 and ♥9 respectively) when determining their relative rank among each other?

Comment: Never been to this stack before, so it's possible I've tagged the question incorrectly; please let me know what the correct tags should be if I've labeled it wrongly.

Comment: I have never heard of this type of poker, interesting though. I'm sure if you worked out the maths for it you'd find that it'd be a lot hard to make a flush with say ♥4, ♥4 that just 5 random suits, so from a maths pov it should be better than a random flush, and likewise a flush with a double pair again should be higher ranked flush, i.e. ♥9, ♥9, ♥J, ♥4, ♥4. What's the game called?

Comment: @Grinch91 It's just 5-card draw—each player is given 5 cards, they're allowed to, once, replace as many in their hand as they choose, and then what they get after the discard is what they have to the end of the round. Maybe I'm using the wrong name for it? My poker knowledge is highly piecemeal. Anyways, if each player is given 5 cards, and they have the option of redrawing up to 5 cards, then each player could go through 10 cards, meaning a single 52 card deck won't sustain more than 5 players without replacing the deck with the discards—which some dealers don't want to do.

Answer (score 1):

If your playing five card draw, I would say no to there being any new types of hands by default, besides five of a kind.

Having said that, you can add those hands if you like, it is your game and your welcome to make modifications that seem fun and interesting if you like. That's how poker evolves.

Just a note, were I am at we play lots of variations of five card draw games, they always play with 7 players max. Running out of cards is rare in most variants, although sometimes in a game they call "Archie" (Hi low split game with some odd qualifying rules on the high and low) if the game is loose they run out of cards often enough where the player under the gun is not dealt in and they deal it 6 handed. If your running out of cards often consider just dealing the player under the gun out.